# How to add an image in TCPDF

Tags: image, magento, pdf, tcpdf

I want to add an image in header using TCPDF in my Magento store.

I am doing this:

```
$tcpdf = new TCPDF_TCPDF();
$img = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/dhl/logo.jpg');

$PDF_HEADER_LOGO = $tcpdf->Image('@' . $img);//any image file. check correct path.
$PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH = "20";
$PDF_HEADER_TITLE = "This is my Title";
$PDF_HEADER_STRING = "This is Header Part";

$tcpdf->SetHeaderData($PDF_HEADER_LOGO, $PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, $PDF_HEADER_TITLE, $PDF_HEADER_STRING);

$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route_'.time().'.pdf', 'I');
```

What steps I have to follow if I want to add my store name (left corner) and logo (right corner)?

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to generate the pdf using the `WriteHTML()` here is a little trick to add image without use of `image()` function.

Simply use the HTML `<img>` as below,

`$image_path = 'path/to/image';
 $print = '<p>some text here...</p>';
 $print .= '<img src=" '. $image_path  .' ">'`;

and you can use inline css to apply height, width etc.

Comment: Not worked for me dear, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

TCPDF is tricky about inserting images as HTML. It implements few hacks to tell what is being loaded:

1. inserting image with `src` attribute as **absolute path** - [must have star](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/main/tcpdf.php#L6937) `*` prefix:

   `<img src="*/var/www/my-image.png">`
2. inserting image with `src` attribute as **relative path** - both examples are treated as relative paths:

   `<img src="/var/www/my-image.png">`

   `<img src="var/www/my-image.png">`

Note, that relative paths are calculated differently on linux and windows - what works correctly on windows may not work well on linux. That is caused by checking [first character in a path string](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/main/tcpdf.php#L19010) as a forward slash `/`, which is considered a linux root and the path will be recalculated - relative path will append to a global variable `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

3. Loading [base-64 encoded string](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/main/tcpdf.php#L19001) - must have `@` prefix in `src` attribute:

   `<img src="@iVBORw0KGgoAAggfd0000555....">`

   `<img src="@'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)).'" width=50 height=35>`

This is safe bet if you want to avoid issues with calculating correct path, but adds extra I/O overhead, because TCPDF will attempt to store supplied data as temporary image file in order to determine image width & height.

UPDATED:

Since TCPDF 6.4 (2020-07-23) there is new setting `allowLocalFiles` which is by default false. Set it to `true` and load local file with protocol `file://` prefix:

```
$tcpdf->allowLocalFiles = true;
<img src="file:///var/www/my-image.png">   # linux
<img src="file://c:\\images\my-image.png"> # windows
```

Comment: Not worked for me dear, thanks :)

Comment: @Kamlesh Updated answer, maybe will help - enable `allowLocalFiles`.

Comment: Absolute and Relative both paths not worked for me. I used `K_PATH_IMAGES` constant of tcpdf for setting images path in img html tag and it worked for me. `<img src="'.K_PATH_IMAGES.'logo-english.jpg" alt="logo-english.jpg" width="220" />;` Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. First of all `$PDF_HEADER_LOGO` is suppose to be an image file name, not image data - as in default implementation of Header() function. There is, however, one important thing to remember, exact location depends on `K_PATH_IMAGES` constant, which should contain path to images folder. If its defined before including TCPDF library its ok, if not TCPDF checks some default paths and first existing is used as images directory. Those directories are:

- ./examples/images/
- ./images/
- /usr/share/doc/php-tcpdf/examples/images/
- /usr/share/doc/tcpdf/examples/images/
- /usr/share/doc/php/tcpdf/examples/images/
- /var/www/tcpdf/images/
- /var/www/html/tcpdf/images/
- /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/tcpdf/images/
- K_PATH_MAIN (which is root tcpdf folder)

So either define constant before, or put your file to one of above directories, and then pass only file name as first argument to `SetHeaderData` and it should work.

To have something similar for Footer you need to extend base TCPDF_TCPDF class and overwrite its Footer method.

Example:

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF_TCPDF {

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'COMPANY NAME', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
        $this->Image('/path/to/image.jpg', 500)
    }
}
```

You'll probably need to work out exact coordinates. Especially in Image it depends on your dimensions, you can add another parameter to Image function being y coordinate, and two others - width and height of image.

And most importantly I recommend checking great examples section on TCPDF page:

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Comment: Do you have an idea where to extend this class in magento ?

Comment: I recommend using lib, you probably use it for TCPDF anyway. Create folder there, and put your extended class in some file. In it also include TCPDF, so one library includes the other. Then in the createPdf (or any) method in whatever controller/observer/model you are using just include/require it like this: `require(Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/mypdf/mypdf.php');`

Comment: Deus Ex Machina. Gratias multas!